# Access mongo db from shell which is created using node application

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongo-shell

Hi I am new to node and mongo DB development. I created one simple node application. I am using mongoDB. I have initialise mondo db and able to insert some data. In my app.js I added DB connection like as follow:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
```

My schema class looks like

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let UserSchema = new Schema({
    // publisherId: {type: String, required: true},
    userName: {type: String, required: true},
    age: {type: Number, required: true}
},{timestamps: true });


// Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

now I want to access same data from command line so I tried to connect my database.

```
mongo mongodb://localhost:27017
```

It connect with this db without any error. When I try to access the data it does not show any data.I check which all databases are available. it shows default test database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is missing from your connection string.

Try something like:

```
const connect = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-database')
}
```

I guess mongoose is using `default` as a default when the connection string does not specify any database to use.